# WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng) returning zero versus the correct sum

Tags: vba, excel

The message box for this returns '0' instead of the correct summed value of the column and nothing gets pasted into Sheet1/D16.

Where am I going wrong here?  I am trying to sum a column from one workbook and paste the value of that summed column into a cell in a different workbook.

Code:

```
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim lAnswer As Variant

Set rng3 = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("P9:P50000")

lAnswer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng3)

'MsgBox lAnswer

wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D16").Value = lAnswer
```

Sample Data, which has spaces in it like this:

```
Header Name
3545.0

24.95


0.0
```

Comment: code works for me, no issues.  Make sure the "numbers" are exactly that, numbers and not text that look like numbers.  Make sure the column is set to "General" and try retyping a few of the numbers.

Comment: another way to verify it's numbers if you run a manual `SUM` form on the data inside a cell.

Comment: What locale are you on? If your locale is North European, then these numbers should use comma as decimal separator, not dot. On my locale, if I do this replacement, the sub works as expected, even if I format the numbers as text. If I use dot as decimal separator, the result is indeed 0.

Comment: @Pnuts: several cells and the alignment is as it appears above.  Several blank spaces in a column with numbers.

Comment: @Scott - I never thought of that, though after changing them to a number, the problem persists, returning 0 instead of a value.

Comment: @EricKing changing the number format doesn't change the value, but there are few workarounds https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-numeric values like text are ignored by `SUM`, but you can try converting the texts to numbers:

```
lAnswer = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate("SUM(--P9:P50000)")
```

Possible workaround for non-numeric text values:

```
lAnswer = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate("sum(if(iserr(--P9:P50000),0,--P9:P50000))")
```

Comment: Nice approach, the only problem is if the "blanks" are not true blanks, but empty strings placed there by a formula or a space this will error.

Comment: This solution resolved my issue! Thank you for your time and energy Slai.